# LLVM IR Array Move with c++ api

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have the following problem with llvm and c++: Given an array, I want to shift every entry of that array by one to the right, i.e., I want to implement the following c code:

```
int arr[5];
for(int i=1;i<5;++i){
   arr[i] = arr[i-1];
}
```

I tried the following c++ code:

```
  IntegerType *Int32Ty = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(M.getContext(););
  GlobalVariable *arrVariable;
  arrVariable = new GlobalVariable(M, PointerType::get(Int32Ty, 0), false,
                 GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0, "__arr");
  for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_LENGTH;++i){
     Constant* fromIdx =  Constant::getIntegerValue(Int32Ty, llvm::APInt(32, i-1));
     Value *fromLocPtrIdx =   IRB.CreateGEP(arrVariable, fromIdx);
     Constant* toIdx =  Constant::getIntegerValue(Int32Ty, llvm::APInt(32, i));
     Value *toLocPtrIdx =   IRB.CreateGEP(arrVariable, toIdx);
     StoreInst *MoveStoreInst = IRB.CreateStore(fromLocPtrIdx,toLocPtrIdx);
  }
```

where `__arr` is defined as:

```
__thread u32  __arr[ARRAY_LENGTH];
```

However, when compiling, this yields the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: __arr: TLS definition in ../inject.o section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference in /tmp/test-inject.o
```

What is the right way to move values in an arrays using the llvm c++ api?

Comment: You need to specify that your global variable is "thread_local". I will write an answer when I've figured out what you actually do to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your global variable is `thread_local`.

The way to do that is to add the thread-local mode to your global creation:

```
arrVariable = new GlobalVariable(M, PointerType::get(Int32Ty, 0), false,
                 GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0, "__arr", nullptr, InitialExecTLSModel);
```

The exact mode depends on what your target is, but I think `InitialExecTLSModel` is a generally "good starting point".